# External function call from JSNI is not working

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, gwt, jsni

I am trying to translate this JavaScript code to JSNI code.

**Script Imports**

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.typeahead.min.js"></script>
<script src="autocompletetest/autocompletetest.nocache.js"></script>
```

---

**Script**

```
$('#q').typeahead({  
    minLength: 1,  
    order: "asc",  
    group: true,   
    groupMaxItem: 6,  
    hint: true,  
    dropdownFilter: "All",  
    href: "https://en.wikipedia.org/?title={{display}}",  
    template: "{{display}}, <small><em>{{group}}</em></small>",  
    source: {  
        country: {  
            data: data.countries  
        },  
        capital: {  
            data: data.capitals  
        }  
    },
    ...
```

**To**

```
$doc.getElementsByClassName("q").typeahead({
    ...
})
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
@com.citi.sevi.client.AutocompleteTest::loadJquery()([]): $doc.getElementsByClassName(...).typeahead is not a function
```

What could be causing this error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question to make the code more readable and hopefully get more people to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `$` function isn't just a `getElementsByClassName` wrapper, it wraps the result in a `jQuery` object, where the plugins live. To call the `typeahead` method, you **have** to use `$win.$("q")`

Comment: thanks Tom, This syntax worked perfectly by just adding $wnd to the existing code.  `$wnd.$('#q').typeahead({ ` . I used exactly the same syntax on "SmartGWT". Nothing is getting displayed, for that matter. The `$wnd.$('#q').length` itself is 0. the object is not getting recognized. Any thoughts Why ?

Comment: The solution for implementing the jquery and external js with Smart gwt is defined in the below link [https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/DomIntegration.html]